# KeyDown event is not being triggred in UserControl

Tags: c#, winforms, keyboard, focus, keyevent

I have a `UserControl` that has a `TreeView` and a `TabControl`. This usercontrol is being hosted in a normal form.

If user selects something from the treeview, a custom picturebox will be added to a tabpage of the tabcontrol. Now I want to handle keys over this picturebox, but the event I created inside the custompicturebox is not being called. What I want is to handle Arrow keys, but the focus stays on the treeview so arrow keys just happen in the treeview.

I aded the code to give focus to the picturebox when user clicks it, but it doesnt help removing focous from treeview. Here is part of my code in custompicturebox control:

**Update**
It seems that only special keys like ARROW keys are not working, my guess is because arrow keys are being registred by the treeview. If I change the `KeyDown` event in the picturebox to use character keys, it works!

```
private void IcPackageViewBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
    {
        OnPinClicked(_pinMap[_pinRectIndex].Pin);

        if (_pinRectIndex < _pinMap.Count)
            _pinRectIndex++;
        else
            _pinRectIndex = 0;
    }
}
    //Mouse Down Event
private void PackageViewBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Focus();
    BringToFront(); //bring to front works! maybe it means focus should work also?
 }
```

In the form that hosts this UserControl, I have the `KeyPreview` set to `True` but I also have to other events onthis form. maybe this is why I can not get keypress inside the customcontrol?

```
    private void MainForm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Modifiers == Keys.Control)
        {
            projectBrowser.ControlKeyIsDown = true;
            e.Handled = true;
        } 
     }

    private void MainForm_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.LControlKey || e.KeyCode == Keys.RControlKey || e.KeyCode == Keys.ControlKey || e.KeyCode == Keys.Control)
        {
            projectBrowser.ControlKeyIsDown = false;
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

And here is what the program looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle this is to override the Form's [ProcessCmdKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.processcmdkey) method. There you will get WM_KEYDOWN messages before they are dispatched to the target control (the control with focus). There you can perform your own logic for dealing with keystrokes and allow or disallow further processing of the message.